# how can find which records are inserted / updated for particular date in sql if date related field not available in table?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm using sql server 2008 as a backend for my project.

My database table not contains any date related field then how can i find which records are inserted / updated for particular date ?

**I want to perform above operation on existing data from my table**

Is it possible? If yes then please let me know.

Comment: I added some extra information related to my scenario which is highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

For existing records in the table, I dont think you can find it. But for the new records, you could create a [TRIGGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) which will update another table with the primary key and a date field

Answer (score 0):

You can enable Change Tracking option on this table.
[Check Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc305322.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could add INSERT and UDPATE triggers to your tables that write the ID of the record being updated and the current date/time to an additional audit table. Then you can query the audit table

```
CREATE    TRIGGER RecordInsertTrigger ON MyTable FOR INSERT
AS
INSERT INTO 
AuditTrail 
(
RecordID,
ActionDate
)
SELECT
RecordID,
getdate()
FROM 
inserted
```

And then create a similar trigger for UPDATE.

You can extend the AuditTrail table to include other relevant information live UserID etc.